# SQL Server configure distribution wizard does not appear

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, distributed, sql-agent

I am stuck with a big problem. I use SQL Server 2012 to distribute data. 
I followed [this article](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/creating_publication.htm#step1), but I encountered a problem. When I right-click on replication, pop-up shows but doesn’t have choose configure distribution like in the article.

This is what I want:

[image]

and that is what I encountered:

[image]

Please tell my why ?

Comment: It seems you have an **Express** version (not a full Standard or Enterprise version) of SQL Server installed which only partially supports replication

Comment: so now can I update express version to full Standard or Enterprise or I must install from start ?

Comment: You have to **buy a license** for either SQL Server Standard or Enterprise, and re-install that new licensed version